# How to suppress command-line defintions from being exported to a sub-make?

Tags: makefile

The makefile may be something like the following:

```
MAKEOVERRIDES=

all:
    @$(MAKE) recursive

recursive:
    @echo $(foo)


.PHONY: all
.PHONY: recursive
```

If I run:

```
$ make foo=bar
```

I get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
bar
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'
```

The idea to suppress command-line definitions is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html):

> The command line variable definitions really appear in the variable
>   'MAKEOVERRIDES', and 'MAKEFLAGS' contains a reference to this variable.
>   If you do want to pass flags down normally, but don't want to pass down
>   the command line variable definitions, you can reset 'MAKEOVERRIDES' to
>   empty, like this:
>
> ```
>  MAKEOVERRIDES =
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To suppress a variable from being exported to sub-make use `unexport`:

```
MAKEOVERRIDES=
unexport foo

all:
    @$(MAKE) recursive

recursive:
    @echo $(foo)


.PHONY: all
.PHONY: recursive
```